# Nuget Packages Installation

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget

I have a solution which has a two projects. In the both the projects I have packages.config file which has the list of packages that the project uses. Whenever I build the solution I'm getting the below error

**The command "*****\Tools\nuget install \packages.config -o \Packages" exited with code 3.**

(replaced folder path with ******)

I have installed all the packages manually using package manager console. The installation is successful. When I build the solution now i'm getting the below error

**The command "*****\Tools\nuget install \packages.config -o \Packages" exited with code 1.**

I have cleared the cache of packages. Still I get this error. Not sure why the solution build is trying to install the packages.

Comment: Try running the failing nuget command line from a console window. You should see the actual error message instead of just the exit code.

Comment: I have installed all the packages from console window. The packages installation was successful. But still I get this error.

Comment: I mean run NuGet.exe from the Windows console (cmd.exe) outside of Visual Studio using the command line that is exiting with code 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `-verbosity detailed` to your command `*\Tools\nuget install \packages.config -o \Packages` to get detailed error message to help you investigate the cause.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening in a new CI build I set up yesterday. The problem was that `NuGet.exe` wasn't at the specified path.

"exited with code 3." wasn't an error from `NuGet.exe` but from MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using TFS, be sure to include the location of the Nuget package in the `Source Settings` of build definition. This error can indicate it cannot access the files.